# Vue.js - Passing data from parent to child without props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create an easy to use mouse parallax component with Vue.js.

I have two components, a **parallax-container** and a **parallax-element**. The idea is, when the mouse moves inside the **parallax-container**, the parallax effect starts. It then passes the mouse position to the **parallax-element** => using props. It all works fine. But my problem is that, when I want to use it, I get a code like this

```
<parallax-container>
  <template slot-scope="props">
    <parallaxElement
    class="text-container"
    :mousePX="props.mousePositionX"
    :mousePY="props.mousePositionY"
    :isHover="props.isHover"
    :parallaxStrength="-10">
      <h1>MouseParallax</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius, omnis atque. Dolore rerum, doloremque nulla animi neque repellat ad voluptatem cumque cum laudantium aut illo illum placeat nihil inventore ipsa.</p>
    </parallaxElement>

    <parallaxElement
    class="background-image"
    :mousePX="props.mousePositionX"
    :mousePY="props.mousePositionY"
    :isHover="props.isHover"
    :parallaxStrength="-30">
    </parallaxElement>
  </template>
</parallax-container>
```

*parallax-container.vue*

```
<template>
 <div class="horizontal-card" @mousemove="getMousePosition">
     <slot :mousePositionX="mouseX" :mousePositionY="mouseY" :isHover="hovering"></slot>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import parallaxElement from "./parallax-element.vue"
import _ from 'lodash'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      mouseX: 0,
      mouseY: 0,
      hovering: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
     getMousePosition: _.throttle(function(e) {
      this.hovering = true
      this.mouseX = e.pageX
      this.mouseY = e.pageY
    }, 100)
  },
  components: {
    parallaxElement
  }
}
</script>
```

Now my problem is that, for each parallaxElement, I need to pass the :mousePX, :mousePY and :isHover, which feels very useless as it's exactly the same value. How can I avoid having to pass the mouse position and the ishover through props? I was thinking of, for example, listening to the @mousemove event on the parallax-element, and let it communicate the mouse position data directly to its sibling without going through the parent. Seemingly there is no way to do that. Do you have any more clever suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using prop is good, if you want to avoid typing to pass in each component then use `copy...paste`. There is not any better idea than using props.

Comment: or use Vuex. But it isn't really easier than what you are doing. If you think this is tedious, you haven't tried ReactJS yet haha

Comment: @JacobGoh I'm open to any solution. How would you suggest using Vuex in this case?

Comment: before that, you should know that [there is another shortcut that you may want to use](https://alligator.io/vuejs/passing-multiple-properties/). If still want to use Vuex, you should start reading its [doc](https://vuex.vuejs.org) first. It's a centralized state management library.

Comment: @JacobGoh Thank you. You did put me on the right track. I found a way around my problem using the Event Bus. The problem I had with it at first is that it affects all the elements, even when not hovered. So I added a condition in the parallax-container, checking if the component is hovered on or not before getting the data from the event bus.